# Finding a line perpendicular to a line and passing through the intersection of other two lines

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometric-construction

So here is the question as in my text book

> Find the equation of the line through the intersection of $2x - 3y + 4 = 0 $ and  $3x + 4y - 5 = 0$ and perpendicular to $6x - 7y + c = 0$

so I calculated the point of intersection of the two line $ 2x - 3y + 4 =0 $ and  $3x + 4y - 5 = 0$  which turned out to be   $ (-\frac{1}{17} , \frac{22}{17})$

Now since the line to be found is perpendicular to the line $ 6x - 7y + c =0 $ so used this formula to find the equation of the line

> since they are perpendicular so product of their slopes will me $-1$ so i used this

.

> let the line pass through point's $(x,y)$ and  $(x_1, y_1) = (-\frac{1}{17} , \frac{22}{17})$ so i't slope will be $ \frac{y - y_1}{x-x_1} = m_1$  now slope of the other line let it be $m_2$ so $m_1*m_2 = -1$.  So on solving this i got the equation of the line to be  $139x + 42y - 125 = 0$

But this not the answer given in my textbook. Am i doing it in wrong way if i am then please a solution will help. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line $6x-7y+c=0$ is $\frac{6}{7}$.  This means that the slope of our desired line is $-\frac{7}{6}$.

Using the point-slope form of a line, we have:

$$y-\frac{22}{17}=-\frac{7}{6}(x+\frac{1}{17})\\[.1in]102y-128=-119x-1\\[.1in]102y+119x-127=0$$

Comment: it is same as i tried no difference you are just moving the number's from left to righ

Comment: @Akash: Note my edit.  You've probably just made an error in the arithmetic.

Comment: how is that even possible i am in this question from last two dates and the same answer was coming and you did in first try this BLOWS

Answer (score 1):

The required answer is one of the members of the family [for some k to be determined later]

$$(2x − 3y + 4) + k(3x + 4y −5) = 0$$

Re-write it as $L_1 : (2 + 3k)x + (–3 + 4k)y + (4 – 5k) = 0$

such that $m(L_1) = \frac {– (2 + 3k)}  {(4k – 3)}$

Given that $L_2 : 6x − 7y + c = 0$ with $m(L_2) = \frac {6}{7}$

‘$L_1$ is perpendicular to $L_2’$ implies $\frac {– (2 + 3k)}{(4k – 3)} \cdot \frac {6}{7} = –1$

∴ $k = 33/10$

Putting this value back in $L_1$ will give you the required result (which is $119x + 102y - 125 = 0$, machine confirmed)